# Vuejs : How can I console.log() all form inputs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I oftenly need to debug my form inputs

I hate having to do this huge & long and sometimes missing vars ...

```
console.log(this.type, this.name, this.url, this.timezone, this.startDate, this.endDate, this.startTime, this.endTime, and 10 more variables .... )
```

Is there a way to console.log(ALL inputs in a form) ?

I've tried

```
getAllData(id) {
        let myForm = document.getElementById(id)
        let formData = new FormData(myForm)
        const data = {}
        // need to convert it before using not with XMLHttpRequest
        for (let [key, val] of formData.entries()) {
            Object.assign(data, { [key]: val })
        }
        console.log(data)
    },
```

and call it like so :

```
this.getAllData('form')
```

I got this in my console

[image]

I can't make sense from any of it...

---

## Try # 2

I've tried

```
getAllData(id) {
    let myForm = document.getElementById(id)
    console.log(
        Array.from(myForm.elements).map((e) => {
            return e.value
        })
    )
},
```

I get better result now, but I would like to see the key along with the value.

This is what I see now.. (only the value)

[image]

Comment: As far as i know that's not possible, but what you could do is define all your inputs within an object. So you can just log your object like this `console.table(this.formData)`

Comment: just seen your edit, you shouldn't be using `document.getElementById` and grabbing the form, instead, you should be using a model, if you really have to use it then swap out `Object.assign(data, { [key]: val })` with `this.$set(this.form.values, key, value)` to assign to a model

Answer (score 3):

How about scoping your form values in a `form` value, i.e:

```
data: () => ({
  form: {
    errors: {},
    values: {
      type: '', 
      name: ''
    }
  }
})
```

You can then simply do `console.log(this.form)`, or plop `<pre>{{ form }}</pre>` in the template for a JSON output.

Additionally, if you add `values` and `errors` within the `form` value you can do  your validation then contain things when outputting, i.e

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="input-type">Type</label>
  <input id="input-type" v-model="form.values.type" type="text" :class="['form-control', { 'is-invalid': form.errors.type }]" placeholder="Enter the type of the thing...">
  <div v-if="form.errors.type" class="invalid-feedback">
    {{ form.errors.type }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use vanilla JS for that, let's say you have the following HTML:

```html
  <form id="myform">
    <input name="input-1" type="text"/>
    <input name="input-2" type="text"/>
    <button type="submit">Hello</button>
  </form>
```

and then plain JS

```js
var myForm = document.getElementById('myform');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(Array.from(myForm.elements).map((el) => {
    return `${el.name}: ${el.value}`; // if you have name attribute on inputs
  }))
});
```

Example on jsbin: https://jsbin.com/tixiduzuyi/edit?html,js,console,output

Solution based on [HTMLFormElement.elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements), so if you have a `<form>` element you could have access to all your `.elements` whiting that form, you can also filter by `input` type, in order to exclude buttons or checkboxes (if needed).

Comment: In order to see key, you will need to make sure that your inputs have some kind of unique key identification, let's say `name` attribute (like in example above) then you can add (in your console log):
`return {[el.name]: el.value};` or as plain string ```return `${el.name}: ${el.value}```;

Answer (score 1):

I find it easiest to [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (using the `...` operator) the form's `entries` into a `console.log()` call, which creates an array of key-value pairs for the entries:

```js
const formData = new FormData(formElement)
console.log(...formData.entries())
```

This yields a single line in Chrome's console like this:

[image: screenshot]

...and you can expand each entry if needed:

[image: screenshot expanded]

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-logging-form-data?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: dope.. Thanks Tony.